# IP grade for specific plastic case

Tags: plastic, circuits, waterproofing

I´m designing an access control device and I need to place it in a plastic case so it can be easily installed on a wall, for example.
Also, the PCB will have a special coating for humidity protection.

Regarding [IP code grading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_Code) for dust and water protection I would like to know:

- If the device is on the outside without protection (roof or similar), would an IP54 plastic case be enough?
- If the device is on the outside but it is protected with a roof or similar, would an IP54 plastic case be enough?
- If this is not correct, what would be a right IP code grading for the case?

Comment: Are you expecting rain like Noah’s flood?

Comment: No, normal rain, no Noah flood expected

Comment: I suggest IP64 or better.

Comment: IP5- will not prevent *all* dust penetration. We have no idea where in the world you are, so we can't decide for you if IP5- is "good enough" or you really need IP6-. IP-4 will not protect if the box might be underneath a water leak or overflow from the roof guttering, etc. I would go for IP64 or IP65 depending on where the device will be mounted, and if you are designing it for use by other people, definitely IP65.

Comment: @alephzero Thank you for your answer. You can post it as an answer.